# Assign the function result of a script $.get() to arbitrary variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure the title is accurate, wasn't sure how to express it better.

I have a controller that returns `text/javascript` with the purpose of dynamically building a form. Unfortunately returning JSON is inadequate, because I need to include validation functions as well.

An example of what I'm returning:

```
(function () {
    return {
        name: "bla",
        validation: function() { 
            alert('juhu');
        }
    }; 
}());
```

It's wrapped in `();` so it parses correctly on the client side `get`. The function returns an object because I want to assign it on the client side to whatever I need, rather than assigning to, say `window.foo`, inside the returned data and dealing with it that way on the client side.
I can get it working the following way.

```
$.get('/api/formdata', function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    var foo = eval(data);

    foo.validation();
    console.log('GET OK', textStatus, jqxhr, data, foo.name);
}).fail(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log('GET failed', textStatus, jqxhr, data);
});
```

Since the data returned is treated as a string, I need to use `eval()` in order to kickstart the invocation.

My question is: is there a better way for the object assignment?

Comment: You might want to try JSONP (with the actual JS literal, not JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

1. Use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) to dynamically include a script. But you'll have to change the code in your script a little bit, as the return value will be lost when the file gets evaluated by jQuery. F.e. change the code to:

   `function getFormData() {
       return {
           name: "bla",
           validation: function() { 
               alert('juhu');
           }
       }; 
   }`

   Then in the `$.getScript` callback, just call `var data = getFormData();`
2. Use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType` set to `JSONP` so jQuery takes care of loading the script and executing a function.

   `$.ajax({
       url: 'dynamicform.js',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp: false,
       jsonpCallback: 'getFormData',
       success: function(result){
           // do something with the result :)
       }
   });`

Comment: Other than setting the accept headers properly, what's the benefit of using `$.getScript()`. I still need to `eval()` the result.

Comment: You do not, the script will be executed after it has been loaded. Try adding a `console.log("executed");` to the file.

Comment: Checked the source and `$.getScript` calls `$.get` with `"script"` parameter, which in turn will call `$.globalEval` on the downloaded script. See [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L17)

Comment: The first option seems more desirable, but can I not use an anonymous function somehow? I know at this point it's nitpicking, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary "conventions". It's for a tenant-type system so I'd like to avoid as much typo prone errors as much as possible.

Comment: Then I guess you'll need to stick with the `eval` method as in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Validation functions don't need to be written in your form, you can build them using APIs that will just field's id or class to validate the content (like jQuery Validation plugin)